# Time between Actions of a Task in Tasker

Tags: android, tasker

I want to create a Task in tasker which performs several clicks. I want 75 simulated screen taps within a second. I'm running a shell command:  inpet tap x y

No matter wether I queue a number of actions in the Task itself or if I do a for loop in the action itself whenever I actually perform the task it takes way too long (about a second) between every single click.

How can I perform several screen taps within a very short time?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Tasker forum page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/tasker/slow%7Csort:relevance/tasker/UKVgjPC7CaY/HGxdXSM06m4J) seems to indicate the slowness is a known and unsurprising issue. Mention was made of a couple of potential alternatives:

- [RepetiTouch](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2270795)
- [AutoInput](http://joaoapps.com/)